# Pandas/Python equivalent of complex ifelse match in R

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, match

My goal is to get the pandas equivalent of the below R code:

```
df1$String_1_check = ifelse(df1$String_1 == df2[match(df1$String_2, df2$String_2), 1], TRUE, FALSE)
```

If the value in the nth row of column String_1 of df1 equals the first column of df2 where the nth row of column String_2 of df1 matches String_2 of df2, then True in a new column String_1_check, else False in String_1_check.

df1 has many instances of the same values in String_1 and String_2, and df2 only has one instance of each possible value in String_1. String_3 is not unique. With these sample dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'String_1': ['string 1', 'string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 1'], 'String_2': ['string a', 'string a', 'string b', 'string a', 'string c']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'String_3': ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3'], 'String_2': ['string a', 'string b', 'string c']})

   String_1  String_2
0  string 1  string a
1  string 1  string a
2  string 2  string b
3  string 3  string a
4  string 1  string c

   String_3  String_2
0  string 1  string a
1  string 2  string b
2  string 3  string c
```

The desired output would be:

```
   String_1  String_2  String_1_check
0  string 1  string a  True
1  string 1  string a  True
2  string 2  string b  True
3  string 3  string a  False
4  string 1  string c  False
```

I have tried `np.where`, `isin`, `pd.match` (deprecated now), but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `map` without change the order of your original `df`

```
df1['String_1_check']=list(zip(df1['String_1'],df1['String_2']))
df2.index=list(zip(df2['String_3'],df2['String_2']))
df2['Check']=True
df1['String_1_check']=df1['String_1_check'].map(df2['Check']).fillna(False)

Out[764]: 
   String_1  String_2  String_1_check
0  string 1  string a            True
1  string 1  string a            True
2  string 2  string b            True
3  string 3  string a           False
4  string 1  string c           False
```

Comment: This ended up working the best for my real data situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Assigning the value back to `df1` like the original `R` you can do:

```
In []:
df1['String_1_check'] = df1.merge(df2, how='left')['String_3'] == df1['String_1']
df1

Out:
   String_1  String_2  String_1_check
0  string 1  string a            True
1  string 1  string a            True
2  string 2  string b            True
3  string 3  string a           False
4  string 1  string c           False
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two dataframes and check if strings 1 and 3 match (edited to incorporate a suggestion by AChampion):

```
dfnew = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
dfnew["String_1_check"] = (dfnew.String_1 == dfnew.String_3)
del dfnew["String_3"]
print(dfnew)
#   String_1  String_2 String_1_check
#0  string 1  string a           True
#1  string 1  string a           True
#2  string 3  string a          False
#3  string 2  string b           True
#4  string 1  string c          False
```

Comment: I was also trying with merge but note that it loses the order of df1. Don't know if it's important though.

Comment: Rows can be sorted in any order, if necessary.

Comment: You can keep the order if you do `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`, so `df1['String_1_check'] == df1.merge(df2, how='left')['String_3'] == df1['String_1']`, is equivalent to the original `R` code which assigned the result back to `df1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df2.String_3` is unique, create a series out of `df2` and use it in a `map` to compare against `df1.String_2`.  This will be fast considering `map` is constant time look-ups compared to `merge`.

In the event that `df2.String_3` is **not** unique, notice that OP requires that we only concern ourselves with the row in which we find the first match from `df1.String_1`.  That means we can make `df2.String_3` unique by using `drop_duplicates`

```
df1.String_1.map(df2.set_index('String_3').String_2).eq(df1.String_2)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Modified version for non-uniqueness

```
df1.String_1.map(
    df2.drop_duplicates('String_3').set_index('String_3').String_2
).eq(df1.String_2)
```

Use `pd.DataFrame.assign` to create a copy of `df1` that includes a new column.

```
df1.assign(
    String_1_check=df1.String_1.map(
        df2.drop_duplicates('String_3').set_index('String_3').String_2
    ).eq(df1.String_2)
)

   String_1  String_2  String_1_check
0  string 1  string a            True
1  string 1  string a            True
2  string 2  string b            True
3  string 3  string a           False
4  string 1  string c           False
```

---

**Timing**
In this simulation, size of `df2` is static.  I didn't feel like modeling unique values.
*Code Below*

[image]

```
pir = lambda df1, df2: df1.assign(String_1_check=df1.String_1.map(df2.drop_duplicates('String_3').set_index('String_3').String_2).eq(df1.String_2))
achamp = lambda df1, df2: df1.assign(String_1_check=df1.merge(df2, how='left').eval('String_3 == String_1'))

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000]),
    columns='pir achamp'.split()
)

for i in results.index:
    d1 = pd.concat([df1] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d1, df2)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d1, df2, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=20))

results.plot(loglog=True)
```

Comment: I knew `merge` wasn't going to be fast - interestingly I built my `map` in reverse ;) `df1['String_2'].map(df2.set_index('String_2')['String_3']) == df1['String_1']` - same result. +1

Comment: I also took liberties with your function and used `eval`.  That is a performance handicap with smaller data and advantageous with larger data.  But it's prettier when wrapped in a `lambda`.

Comment: I really like this. Unfortunately, the values in String_3 are not unique. I've edited my question to reflect that. Sorry for any confusion. Do you have another solution that is faster than `merge`?

Comment: Actually, since you only care to compare against the row in `df2` that constitutes the first time that you find a match from `df1`... then you can drop the duplicates and make it unique.  I'll update post.

Comment: @AndrewRussell also note that if `String_3` is not unique, you'll have funny issues with `merge` as well.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes that's the problem I'm running into I think. For my real data, no answer works so far. Dropping the duplicates from `String_3` removes critical data that I need to compare between both `String_2` columns.

Comment: @AndrewRussell then there is a missing piece to the logic you've stated.   Maybe you want to see if there exist any such row in `df2` where `String_1 == String3` and `String_2 == String_2`.